# How to make Sentry work with already existing nextConfig that is an async function?

Tags: asynchronous, next.js, async-await, sentry

So I have this nextjs project and I'm trying to add Sentry to it, but there is a problem that my nextConfig variable in next.config.js is an async function which nextjs itself accepts as a `module.export` since v12.0.10, but Sentry does not. You need to wrap your `module.export` into a `withSentryConfig` whose first argument must be the nextConfig but this function does not accept nextConfig if it's an async function.

My next.config.js file looks like this:

```
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

const prismic = require('@prismicio/client');

const sm = require('./sm.json');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = async () => {
  const client = prismic.createClient(sm.apiEndpoint);

  const repository = await client.getRepository();
  const locales = repository.languages.map(lang => lang.id);

  return {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    compiler: {
      styledComponents: true,
    },
    i18n: {
      // These are all the locales you want to support in
      // your application
      locales: locales,
      // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
      // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
      defaultLocale: locales[0],
      localeDetection: false,
    },
  };
};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  nextConfig,
  { silent: true },
  { hideSourcemaps: true },
);
```

Is there a workaround to this?

"@sentry/nextjs": "^7.42.0"

"next": "13.1.2"

react": "18.2.0"

I've tried playing around with it exporting it in multiple ways like putting await in front of nextConfig and calling it, making it with .then blocks instead of async await but nothing seems to working.

```
module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  nextConfig(),
  { silent: true },
  { hideSourcemaps: true },
);
```

```
module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  await nextConfig(),
  { silent: true },
  { hideSourcemaps: true },
);
```

But they don't seem to be working. If I convert nextConfig to an object an manually type in the locales variable it works so I know the async function is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an asynchronous function called something like `buildConfig` that returns an object wrapped with `withSentryConfig`. See the following...

```
const buildConfig = async () => {
  const client = prismic.createClient(sm.apiEndpoint);

  const repository = await client.getRepository();
  const locales = repository.languages.map(lang => lang.id);

  return withSentryConfig({
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true,
    compiler: {
      styledComponents: true,
    },
    i18n: {
      // These are all the locales you want to support in
      // your application
      locales: locales,
      // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
      // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
      defaultLocale: locales[0],
      localeDetection: false,
    },
  }, {silent: true}, {hideSourceMaps: true});
}

module.exports = buildConfig();
```